# Access variable from Class in main

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to learn Python and I'm stuck with shared variables between classes.

I have a class that sets a variable like this:

```
class CheckStuff(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, debug):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.debug = debug
    self.newGames = False

  def get_new_games(self):
    return self.newGames

  def set_new_games(self, new_games):
    self.newGames = new_games

  def run(self):
    # DO STUFF #
    # ... #
    self.set_new_games(True)
    return
```

I would like to access `new_games` from my main, I tried like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    debug = True
    t1 = cs.CheckStuff(debug)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    print(cs.CheckStuff(debug).get_new_games())
    exit()
```

But this returns always `False`. Where am I wrong? Any hints appreciated

Comment: Can i have a question? What is the "cs"?

Comment: It is from the import at the top: `import CheckStuff as cs`

Comment: Ok thanks, nexttime you can add this one simple line or remove "cs" to avoid this. The best question is if i can copy paste your code into my IDE and run it without searching undefined methods and variables to delete them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of CheckStuff, which hasn't done anything so its newGames attribute is False. The instance that did run is `t1`, you should use that:

```
print(t1.get_new_games())
```

(Note, there doesn't really seem to be a good reason to use threads here, but never mind.)

Comment: Thanks! There are actually more things I use other threads for just for simplicity I copied only one, which has no point I admit ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the following line

```
 print(cs.CheckStuff(debug).get_new_games())
```

you make a new instance of CheckStuff class, and in the constructor you set `self.newGames = False`. Then, by calling `get_new_game()` method you ask the object to return its `newGame` attribute, which is obviously `False`.